# Argument is not numeric or logical: returning NAargument is not numeric or logical in R

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

So I am using this code below. `maindata` is a table of players, their home towns, and their points per game. I am trying to make a new table that has the cities in one column, and the average points per game in the second (as shown in table A). I keep getting a table with the cities listed and the rows for `AvgPoints` all showing NA. I get this error "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NAargument is not numeric or logical", and it repeats itself hundreds of times. Main data has 3561 observations.

```
point <- maindata%>%
  group_by(City, State) %>%
    summarise(AvgPoints = mean(PTS.1, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Table A

```
   City            AvgPoints
----------------------------
New York City        19.9
Los Angeles          22.1
Boston               13.3
```

Comment: Please check the `str(maindata)` for the type of columns. or specifically `class(maindata$PTS.1)`  May be the 'PTS.1' is not numeric

Comment: @akrun it says they are factors. I am not exactly sure why.

Comment: If there are some elements which are non-numeric i.e. it will read as `character`.  In the new version of R, it should be `character` class instead of `factor` because `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` by default.  My point is that if your column have `c(1.5, 1.2, 'a1')`, it is not a numeric column because one of the element is not numeric.  you can convert to numeric from factor with `maindata %>% mutate(PTS.1 = as.numeric(as.character(PTS.1)))` and then do the group by.  There would be some friendly warning while converting the non-numeric to NA

Comment: @akrun Wonderful, I understand your point and I have applied the function and have got it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert the column to `numeric` first if it is not numeric and then do the group by operation

```
library(dplyr)
maindata %>%
      mutate(PTS.1 = as.numeric(as.character(PTS.1))) %>%
      group_by(City, State) %>%
      summarise(AvgPoints = mean(PTS.1, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```